# Even counting integers Python

Tags: python

Hey guys I have been having a little trouble in trying to count all of the even integers within my list and print the number of even integers. I am new to programming so may not be up to date with the knowledge and terminology of some of you guys on here. If you could help me out that would be great! Here is what i have started already.

```
list = [2,4,5,6,8]
count_even=0
while count_even<len(list):
    if list[count_even]%2==0:
        count_even=count_even + 1
   else:
        list[count_even]%2!=0
        count_even=count_even
   print count_even
```

Comment: And don't use the name 'list' as that's the word used to create a list in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num_list = [2,4,5,6,8]
count_even=0

for n in num_list:
    if n%2==0:
        count_even=count_even + 1
print count_even
```

---

Explanation of changes:

- Change `list` variable name. Don't use the name of a Python object.
- Change from `while` to `for`; Don't need to do list indexing this way
- Remove the `else` block; It's not doing anything right now anyway. There is no point in `count_even=count_even`

Your issue was with indexing. Everything was based on the `count_even` variable. Your `while` loop was continuing while it was less than the length of the list and in your `else` block you weren't incrementing it. Thus, you have an infinite loop if there is an odd number in the list

Comment: Thank you for all of your input. I will try to use it by further bettering myself as a programmer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd make a new temporary list of even integers, then measure the length that:

```
lst = [2,4,5,6,8]
print len([i for i in lst if i %2 == 0])
```

That uses list comprehension. If you want to avoid that, just use a loop, like:

```
lst = [2,4,5,6,8]
count_even=0
for num in lst:
    if num %2 == 0:
        count_even += 1
print count_even
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = [2,4,5,6,8]
count = 0    
for x in list:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print "Even Number:", x
        count=count + 1
print "Count:", count
```

Comment: @APerson ,, Yes, it will print all even numbers and also count the how many even numbers are in the list. That's what the asker need.

Answer (score 2):

```
 filter(lambda x: x%2==0 ,[0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

You can also try the one liner.

```
list = [2,4,5,6,8]
count_even=0
i=0
while i<len(list):
    if list[i]%2==0:
        count_even=count_even + 1
    i=i+1


print count_even
```

You are probably running an infinite loop whernever you encouter an odd number as `count_even` is not increasing.You need to use 2 variables.

Comment: Yes that was my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd favor the for-loop solution, because it demonstrates that you can iterate over the items in the list without needing a separate index variable at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [2,4,5,6,8]
count_even=0
for i in xrange(len(list)):
    if list[i]%2==0:
        count_even += 1
print count_even
```

A couple of things:

- you are using `count_even` as both a counter and as an index value
- not necessary to do anything at all if the number is not even if all you are doing is counting even numbers

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will take that into consideration next time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` also

```
>>> lst = [2,4,5,6,8]
>>> map(lambda x:x%2==0,lst).count(True)
4
```

python 3x:

```
list(map(lambda x:x%2==0,lst)).count(True)
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately i am not familiar with the term lambda and am not sure how to properly apply it to coding.